# Apps can't access internally mounted SSD

Tags: mount, hard-drive, automount

So this question has been asked a bunch of times but the discussion goes over my head. I need a step by step guide to fix this issue.

I have an internally mounted SSD. Its formatted to ext4. I have modified the permissions on the disk to have read/write enabled for SUDO.

Contents of my /etc/fstab file are as follows:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=15ff6a59-4964-43fb-8f6f-35106232108a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4C99-DC9A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Contents of lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 246.5M  1 loop /snap/brave/130
loop1    7:1    0 246.5M  1 loop /snap/brave/129
loop2    7:2    0 323.5M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14
loop3    7:3    0  61.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/1026
loop4    7:4    0  45.2M  1 loop /snap/dotnet-runtime-50/16
loop5    7:5    0 295.7M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2344
loop6    7:6    0  45.2M  1 loop /snap/dotnet-runtime-50/17
loop7    7:7    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop8    7:8    0  61.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1081
loop9    7:9    0  65.4M  1 loop /snap/geforcenow/8
loop10   7:10   0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
loop11   7:11   0  82.6M  1 loop /snap/zotero-snap/26
loop12   7:12   0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop13   7:13   0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12883
loop14   7:14   0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop15   7:15   0 241.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70
loop16   7:16   0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop17   7:17   0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
loop18   7:18   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop19   7:19   0  68.4M  1 loop /snap/zotero-snap/34
loop20   7:20   0 295.6M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2288
loop21   7:21   0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop22   7:22   0  64.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop23   7:23   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop24   7:24   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop25   7:25   0  65.4M  1 loop /snap/geforcenow/9
loop26   7:26   0 242.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/76
loop27   7:27   0  75.8M  1 loop /snap/obsidian/x1
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 118.8G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk /media/amogh/Amogh SSD
```

Mount options in Disks:
[image: Mount Options Disks]

Comment: But what is your issue? What disk is the inaccessible one? `sda` or `sdb`? PLease give an example what happens when you try to access this disk. An error message maybe?

Comment: Any apps (web-browser such as brave, vlc etc. are not able to access sdb. I get the following error when I try to go to this location using file explorer (inside Obsidian). 
"Unable to read the contents of Amogh SSD" Permission Denied. 

I don't think this is software specific issue since none of my apps are able to open this SSD drive.

Comment: Since `sdb` is not in your `/etc/fstab`, and is mounted under `/media/amogh/Amogh SSD` I guess it has been automounted when you tried to access it via GNOME. In that case it should be accessible to you without changing anything to permissions. Maybe you created the problem yourself by the permissions change. Try unmounting the disk, verify that the mount point `/media/amogh/Amogh SSD` disappeared (if not, delete it manually) and mount again. It is hard to say more without knowing what the actual permissions on the mount point (and on the drive contents, if any) are.

Comment: The SSD is accessible. I can navigate, create folders and other stuff. However, the apps can't navigate/access my internal hard-drive.

Comment: "You" navigate, create folders etc. on the SSD also via some app (Nautilus file manager). So if this app can access the SSD, other apps should too. Try default GNOME apps like text editor, imge viewer, video player etc. Are they able to access the SSD? If yes, it means there is no problem. What you may experience is that **snap** apps cannot access the SSD. It's just because of how snap apps work. They are limited in what they can do and many of them cannot access anything outside your `/home`. So mount your SSD in some subdir inside your `/home`, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this. I don't know how to mount inside /home. In disks (app) I see an option to change this. But what should I change it to? See updated image in the question.

Comment: Create a directory that will serve as a mount point, for example `/home/ssd` and change the mount point in the shown dialog to `/home/ssd`.